# Viviani’s curve for a cylinder and sphere intersection in parametric form

Tags: differential-geometry, curves

How to find Vivianis curve of the following intersection in parametric form
\begin{align*}
x^2+y^2&=\frac14\tag{1}
\\
\left(x+\frac12\right)^2+y^2+z^2&=1\tag{2}
\end{align*}

We are given $-1\leq z\leq 1$ and $z=\sin t$

My understanding is that we have to eliminate $x,y,z$ but it’s not clear where the above line comes from...

I have attempted to proceed by solving for z in equation $(2)$ given $x=a\cos t$ and $y=a\sin t$

$$1=(x+a)^2+y^2+z^2$$

I arrive at $z^2=1-\cos^2(t/2)$... not sure how to proceed further...

Comment: I would write the sphere with spherical coordinates and then try to set $\varphi=\vartheta$ and check if they fullfil the equation for the cylinder.

Answer (score -1):

You just can take the spherical coordinates:
$$x= \cos(\theta)\cos(\varphi)-0.5 , y=\cos(\theta)\sin(\varphi), z=sin(\theta). $$
Then set $\varphi=\theta$ and you get
$$x= \cos(\theta)\cos(\theta)-0.5 , y=\cos(\theta)\sin(\theta), z=sin(\theta). $$
You can then check that they fulfil the equation of the cylinder (see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viviani%27s_curve)).

Comment: I left out a crucial piece of info. I need to find the intersection in  parametric form

Comment: I have edited the post further.

Comment: Actually, I don't know that you mean. $(\cos(t)\cos(t)-0.5 ,\cos(t)\sin(t),sin(t))$ is a parametric form. But maybe you can find here a solution https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/667283/how-can-i-parametrize-vivianis-curve?rq=1.